# Applying a single background gradient to a table row

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a background gradient that spans an entire table row? I'm only able to apply the background to individual table cells, even when I'm specifically trying to prevent that. Here is a boiled-down sample that targets Webkit on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cGV47/2/

As you can see, I am using `border-collapse:collapse` and I am specifying `background:transparent` for the `<tr>` and `<th>` child elements, yet the red gradient to the left is repeated for each table cell. I've tried applying the background to the `<tr>` as well, but with the same result as you see now.

To view the code without going to jsfiddle, here it is:

**html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>un</td>
            <td>deux</td>
            <td>trois</td>
            <td>quatre</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**css**

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;border-collapse:collapse;}
table { width:100%; }
thead { background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(222,22,22,1) 0%, rgba(222,222,222,0) 20%, rgba(222,222,222,0) 80%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%); }
thead tr, thead th { background:transparent; }
```

Comment: i can confirm that this is still happening to me in chrome 33. and is a documented bug in chromium

Answer (score 43, accepted):

set `background-attachment:fixed;` on thead and it will work fine

http://jsfiddle.net/cGV47/64/

Comment: The question's so old it's got whiskers on it, but that solution does work great. Thanks @jekcom.

Comment: In case it helps someone else: This worked for me (applying it to a .highlight row instead of thead); however, I strangely needed to add an !important flag to the background-attachment for it to work.  Adding the flag to the background rule as well broke the behavior again.  I could not discern the reason behind either.

Comment: I know this is years later, but this worked for Edge as well... what is it with MS browsers... Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for me. The fiddle in the answer seems to produce the same result as the fiddle in the question.

Comment: Can you help me? I have a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102558/gradient-color-in-html-table

Comment: Such a stupid solution but it works. I'm still baffled that it's not fixed in 8 years.

Answer (score 7):

I think there is a better solution to these:

- Apply the gradient background to the whole table.
- Then apply a solid background for thead and tfooter.

```
table { border:0; border-collapse:collapse;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 40%, rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2)), color-stop(60%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 40%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 40%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 40%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 40%,rgba(108,211,229,0.2) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */            
}

table thead, tfoot {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/5brPL/

Comment: logged in just to upvote this, genius!

Answer (score 2):

I have found myself testing the brand new `repeating-linear-gradient`, which apparently works for `<tr>` elements (I have only tested in Google Chrome though).

The trick is to provide the widest repeating pattern, so that... it does not repeat.

Try this:

```
tr {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        red 0%,
        blue 100%
    );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slyy/2pzwws0d/

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution, but it does do the trick. You just set up each `th` to have 25% of the color range. The example below uses a color range from 0 to 255.

http://jsfiddle.net/cGV47/3/

Same HTML that you already have. Here's the CSS:

```
table { width:100%; }

th {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, 
                                              rgba(191,191,191,1) 100%);
}
th + th {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(191,191,191,1) 0%, 
                                              rgba(128,128,128,1) 100%);
}
th + th + th {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(128,128,128,1) 0%, 
                                              rgba(64,64,64,1) 100%);
}
th + th + th + th {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,64,64,1) 0%, 
                                              rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
```

I found this issue on Google: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122988 but there is no solution.

Firefox does not have this issue (didn't check any other browsers):
http://jsfiddle.net/cGV47/4/