# CSS - Linear Gradient Background Color no-repeat is not working for <tr> if it has multiple tds

Tags: html, css

I want to apply css3 gradient (left and right transparent) background color for a TR element 
**like below**.
[image]

Below code is working fine if it has only one TD element, where as more than one td, background gradient started repeating for each td...

**Am I missing something?**

### [Online Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/2t0pm7bn)

> **CSS**

```
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
table tr td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #000; }
table tr{
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%, rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%, rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%, rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%, rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(29,147,185,0)), color-stop(25%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5)), color-stop(50%,rgba(29,147,185,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(29,147,185,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001d93b9', endColorstr='#001d93b9',GradientType=1 );
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

> **HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">This is working fine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>dolar</td>
        <td>sit</td>
        <td>amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sed aliquam dolor</td>
        <td>sit amet dolor</td>
        <td>varius</td>
        <td>dignissim</td>
        <td>imperdiet</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
table tr td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #000; }
table tr{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%, rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%, rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%, rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%, rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(29,147,185,0)), color-stop(25%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5)), color-stop(50%,rgba(29,147,185,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(29,147,185,0)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001d93b9', endColorstr='#001d93b9',GradientType=1 );
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">This is working fine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>dolar</td>
        <td>sit</td>
        <td>amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sed aliquam dolor</td>
        <td>sit amet dolor</td>
        <td>varius</td>
        <td>dignissim</td>
        <td>imperdiet</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: A) Please put this into a SO snippet, would be really useful. B) Does it work when you apply the bg to the actual table instead of the `tr`?

Comment: In firefox work perfect but in chrome and safari no. Not tested on IE but it's obvious is browser problem.

Comment: **@somethinghere**, added the Code Snippet.. Yes, it is working for table.. but I want to show this bg on mouseover of td, entire row should take the effect..... :(

Comment: Put every tr in a table. It's not very beautiful solution but is crossbrowser.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371846/applying-a-single-background-gradient-to-a-table-row - set your `background-attachment` to `fixed`.

Comment: **@GermanoPlebani**.. thanks for the tip, but I have 100s of rows. If I use this tip, code will become heavy... :(

Comment: **@somethinghere**.. Ecellent.. this trick is working like a Charm... You saved my Day! and Thanks to **"@jekcom"** who has answered this originally by adding... `tr{background-attachment:fixed;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}
table tr td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #000; background:#FFF }
table tr:hover td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #000; background:transparent }
table{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFkOTNiOSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjI1JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFkOTNiOSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjUiLz4KICAgIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iNTAlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMWQ5M2I5IiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjEiLz4KICAgIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iNzUlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMWQ5M2I5IiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuNSIvPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxMDAlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMWQ5M2I5IiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAiLz4KICA8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PgogIDxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZC11Y2dnLWdlbmVyYXRlZCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%, rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%, rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%, rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%, rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(29,147,185,0)), color-stop(25%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5)), color-stop(50%,rgba(29,147,185,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(29,147,185,0)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(29,147,185,0) 0%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 25%,rgba(29,147,185,1) 50%,rgba(29,147,185,0.5) 75%,rgba(29,147,185,0) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001d93b9', endColorstr='#001d93b9',GradientType=1 );
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

Now set td backgound white, then hover set td background transparent

Comment: **@Maheswwaran S**, Thanks for the post... I want this effect to be set only on mouse over of td, relevant tr should take this effect which is not working :(

Comment: **@Maheswaran S**... Thanks mate.. working like a charm.. Upvoting your effort and Accepting your answer too... Thanks a Ton