# Displaying background image behind row in div table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a table to display some values using styled divs of the form below (inline styling for prototyping reasons):

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-row; background: some-color-gradient; background-size: some-numbers">
        <div style="display: table-cell">
            Some Number
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put a background image linear gradient to fill only a certain percentage of the entire 'table-row' level div.  This approach works as intended on firefox but on chrome I get strange behavior.  Instead of filling the row div with the image, each of the child table cells are filled to a certain percent (based on the 'some-number' value).

How can I ensure that the background is applied to the row div and not to each child one?

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle to help understand the question better?

Comment: [Here is one](https://jsfiddle.net/6y73c7dj/1/)  If you open on firefox it will only have one background, but on chrome it has two.

Comment: @chosunOne browsers support everything differntly - I think you need to implement webkit and moz as well - check this fiddle, which is in the extreme. https://jsfiddle.net/y9yetoyt/

Comment: Sorry @Stender, but it seems you omitted the 'table-row' from the display property in your fiddle.  Adding it back in replicates the problem in your fiddle.  Furthermore, adding in the other implementations does not remove the issue.

Comment: Sorry @ChosunOne - missed that - I guess this is a dublicate then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371846/applying-a-single-background-gradient-to-a-table-row

Comment: Thanks @Stender for the find!  It's almost there, but it seems to play weird with background size.  Any suggestions?

Comment: did you implement the background-position:fixed?

Comment: I implemented background-attachment: fixed, but it seems to be putting the background further to the right (and thus behind some other page elements).